# Is it possible to change the switching frequency of a Royer-based ZVS WPT circuit?

Tags: power-electronics, frequency, wireless

From what I have understood so far, the Royer circuit or ZVS system is self oscillating and hence the frequency is determined by the inductance of the primary winding of the coil and voltage supplied.

When designing such a circuit for wireless power transfer, we select a coil with a certain inductance and select capacitors in order to set the resonance of the Tx side. On the Rx side it is necessary to set the resonance frequency close to the Tx side, but not exact. The detuning is required as there is some offset due to coupling and losses.

My question is:

- When the ZVS circuit is in operation, it will start switching at a frequency different from the resonance. Is there any other way to change the switching frequency of a Royer circuit?
- Would one have to just select a coil with a specific inductance value to get the switching frequency in the required frequency range?

I am trying to achieve a specific voltage & current output, I have read that when the switching frequency is reduced, the operating point moves towards resonance, and hence the voltage output increases, and vice versa. I want to test this theory out.

Comment: A couple misconceptions -- the typical "ZVS oscillator" circuit is a Baxandall oscillator, not Royer (magnetic saturation commutated); it is not a switching circuit, but a linear one (just a particularly clever one, once running at full amplitude!); the frequency is simply the natural resonant frequency of the load system (or if multiple resonances, it may simply pick the strongest and stick with that). It sounds like you simply want a fixed-frequency inverter?

Comment: Well i have been working on a wireless power transfer circuit which uses the ZVS oscillator. I have gotten decent results, but I think I am facing quite a bit of losses due to maybe bad tuning, and partly due to the fact the coils on the Tx and Rx are not the best combination(I measured a coupling factor K=0.3 at 7.5mm), but I am stuck with them due size constraints. I Was just exploring the option of,is possible, changing the switching frequency and maybe get a better Efficiency/better working condition on the Rx coil.

Comment: k = 0.3 doesn't sound too bad. Do you know it has to be double resonant? If you are transmitting over a widely variable distance (worst-case k much lower than this?), that range can't be solved by a standalone oscillator. Efficiency is dictated by Q factor of the components, how are they designed/chosen?

Comment: what do you mean by double resonant? It should be fixed distance, I've taken 7.5mm as a starting point, but I think I can make it too maybe 6-6.5mm.

Comment: You seem to be selecting capacitors for the Rx side. Maybe just use more turns and don't tune it at all?

Comment: Well, while selecting coils, I chose the one from Würth electronic. There are a few that I am trying with, a 5.8uH, 6uH, 6.3uH, 24uH as Tx, and a 19.6uH coil for the Rx. Rx Res caps are C0G, with values calculated for resonance set at the Tx end. The k value is similar regardless which coil I take, 0.28-0.303.

Comment: I am stuck using the [RX] (https://www.vishay.com/docs/34547/iwas3222czeb190jf1.pdf) due to size constraints. hence I've been trying to find a coil on the Tx side that is more compatible with it. By not tuning do you mean to just set a Cap value close to but exact to the Tx side?

Comment: I mean you put the rx coil into a FWB into a cap and that's it, you're done, receiver made. You don't have any means of control by the oscillator so V(I) characteristics must be provided with a rx side boost/buck/SEPIC/etc. converter. You can play around with resonance and tuning and passive V(I) curves with a fixed-frequency (or controlled) inverter, but not with an oscillator that's tracking its own output.

Comment: That's an interesting way of coming about it, I will give a shot. Just to reiterate what you said. A normal cap on the Rx side, and then use maybe a voltage regulator(could be something else) to regulate the V(I) characteristics of the received signal.

Comment: FWB then cap. You're making rectified and filtered DC. Coil connects straight to the FWB AC terminals, no cap on it (use a fast-recovery or schottky type FWB or discrete diodes). Just treat it like a transformer.

Comment: I tested this out a little bit, connecting the coil directly to the FWB, and then a couple smoothening caps, I found that the efficiency took a hit, but also the Tx coil was heating up, also the Rx coil.